# PHP Ignoring my max_execution_time

Tags: php, codeigniter, ffmpeg

I have some task in my script that is about converting video with ffmpeg . I do this with codeigniter 2.0.3 and locate the script at libraries and use shell_exec() to run ffmpeg.

There are 3 tasks in my php script.

1. Upload File
2. Convert video to .flv
3. Generate thumb
4. Save to db.

When I upload file, my php script start to convert my uploaded video. But when converting is end about over 5 minutes. Its not continue to generate thumb. And Its say

> PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\AppServ\www\mis\application\libraries\my_video_utility.php on line 102, referer: http://localhost/mis/test/

I have set my max_execution time, max_input_time, etc to 3600 in php.ini also add set_time_limit() and set_ini() in my php script. But, its still get error.

But, when I uploaded short video, its done.

Comment: Have you checked `phpinfo();` that all parameters have been actually changed?

Comment: did you restart php after editing php.ini?

Comment: Could it be the hosting company is blocking you from doing this?  There is a safety setting which disallows you from changing max exec time some hosts like to use.  I'll try to find the setting name

Comment: so you'd be willing to allow requests to run for 1 hour? why aren't you doing this in the background?

Comment: ah found it, it's when php is compiled with safe mode on, idk if it works for the php.ini settings, but I know it would block the max exec command, http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode

Comment: @zerkms yes.. I absolutely change the value. And I have check phpinfo(), its says 3600.

Comment: @Dagon ofcourse.. I always restarting php after editing php.ini

Comment: @mazzzzz It is not hosting company. It is my localhost

Comment: @miki LOL. Its just my experiment how to convert long time video (just like youtube).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok. I do this my self. I have contacted my teacher. There is a something that CodeIgniter not include this in their documentation.

At line 103 in system/core/CodeIgniter.php

```
if (function_exists("set_time_limit") == TRUE AND @ini_get("safe_mode") == 0)
{
    @set_time_limit(300);
}
```

I try to change the value and it works.

Comment: Here's the commit https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/commit/f566af5ffb8f2e8d49bd0b206c6ee29c8bc35a78

Answer (score 2):

Solution to change `set_time_limit()` function in CodeIgniter.php is works, but I'm think it's not good idea to change framework's core files.

I'm found another decision, you can call `set_time_limit()` where you need and it will be overlapp setting of time limit in CodeIgniter.php.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter 2 has the set_time_limit function run with 300. After upgrading to Codeigniter 3, one thing started failing. After viewing this post, I realized that the set_time_limit call was removed in 3, so you may have to add the code in the accepted answer to your particular problem code. I would not recommend adding it back into the Codeigniter.php