# CodeIgniter php script is not running more than 2 minutes??

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a PHP script in my Code Igniter application,
its run on server and fetch some data but its not running more than 2 minutes approx..
and when I run this without using code igniter its works properly..what may be the reason behind this?

Comment: your server is not running correctly, check your Apache error log..

Comment: actualy script is made to fetch data form another server..

Comment: Codeigniter does `set_time_limit(300)` inside its core file. Try setting time limit just above your code if not done that way.

Comment: You should post some relevant code - currently,all we can do is speculate and guess.

Comment: i have aleady post some code below but its not possible to put whole code here and BTW i am sure there is not any issue with script becoz it working well outside codeigniter..

Comment: thanx @air4x its works .. :) by setting **set_time_limit(300)** in the **system/core/CodeIgniter.php**

    **if (function_exists("set_time_limit") == TRUE AND @ini_get("safe_mode") == 0)
    {
        @set_time_limit(300);
    }**

after setting this code script running well..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Ignoring my max\_execution\_time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656031/php-ignoring-my-max-execution-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks @air4x its works . by setting **set_time_limit(300)** in the **system/core/CodeIgniter.php**

```
if (function_exists("set_time_limit") == TRUE AND @ini_get("safe_mode") == 0)
{
    @set_time_limit(300);
}
```

after setting this code script running well..

Comment: I have the same problem as you but when I added your code, it doesn't work or maybe my php version does not apply this fix anymore.... my php version is 7....

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this before you run your code: `set_time_limit(0);`

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

If that doesn't work, you'll need to share what code you are running and what happens when it stops running.

Comment: thanx @Justin but i have already try set_time_limit(1000000); this one but it doesn't work.

Comment: Then you'll need to post more information about the problem. If you don't get an error, you need to check the error logs on the server.

Comment: Also note that you must make sure you’re not running php in safemode. Safemode ignores the set_time_limit() function.

Comment: if (($handle = fopen("./downloads/xyz.csv", "r")) !== FALSE)
  {
   while (($auction_data_arr = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",",'"')) !== FALSE)
   { "SOME CODE HERE"}}

Comment: its reads data from csv file , script runs for apporx 2 minutes every time i try and stores only data its able to read in that time interval..no error message generated..

Comment: Are you uploading a file? You could try: `ini_set('max_input_time', 10000);` Also, I'd set `set_time_limit(0);`

Comment: not working.. but why script running well outside code igniter application when manually initiates?

Answer (score 0):

There must be, Set_time_limit - Sets the maximum execution time of a script.

```
bool set_time_limit ( int $seconds )
```

`When set_time_limit()` called. It returns the counter to zero. In other words, if the default limit is 30 seconds, and after 25 seconds of script execution the `set_time_limit(20)` call is made, then the script will run for a total of 45 seconds before finishing .

Please visit http://php.net/manual/fr/function.set-time-limit.php for more information.