# how to increase max-execution-time in codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter

I am Getting an error

> "504 Gateway Timeout - The gateway did not receive a timely response
>   from the upstream server or application"

after 20 minute of run my Script from Cron
I am using codeigniter version 3 got one solution [php-ignoring-my-max-execution-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656031/php-ignoring-my-max-execution-time)
but Below Code not found in system/core/CodeIgniter.php codeigniter version 3

```
if (function_exists("set_time_limit") == TRUE AND @ini_get("safe_mode") == 0){
@set_time_limit(300);}
```

How to increase max-execution-time in codeigniter 3?

Comment: What is your question? You should post some code you are running and the results you get from that code.

Comment: I'd be looking into why you this is even happening in the first place. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```